# Redirect new blog build on same domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301, craftcms

I know there's a lot of answers on here though none are very specific for this.

Currently I have a domain with a blog section set out like this:

`example.com/news` this is a single page then

```
example.com/news/entries
```

`example.com/news/topics/(topic)` also a single page

So what I'm after is to change my htaccess to change everything from 'news' to 'blog' as we have a lot of social media posts linking to the old news/entries etc.

Currently I was thinking of this:

```
RewriteRule ^/news(.*)$ $1/blog(.*)[L,R=301]
```

Just wondering if this is the right approach as I want everything, including the single page to change from news to blog.

Thank you in advance community.

Comment: Should be easy enough to test whether this does what you want or not, no? (Make that `R=302` fist during testing, so that potentially wrong redirects don’t get cached by your browser.)

Comment: Also you want to take a look again at the examples you mentioned: they all demonstrate that there should not be parenthesis in the target of a rewriting rule and what the `$1` actually contains, so where it belongs.